# Python ldap3 how to get all members of a group

Tags: python, python-3.7, ldap3

I have tried every solution on Stackoverflow for this and none work.
Using python3 and ldap3 I can make the bind with the user and with the service account and I can even extract the users email address. But I cannot verify that he is from a certain group.
I am trying to get all members of the group and then I will see if he exists in that group.

Users DN: **OU=Users,O=Acme**
Who is a member of: **CN=my-users,OU=MyUsers,OU=Groups,O=Acme**

Here is the code I have so far..

```
try:
    l = bind_user(MyServiceAccount, MyServiceAccountPassword)
except Exception as e:
    logger.info(f'Error attempting to bind with ldap server: {e}')
    return(f'Error logging in. Details: {e}')

    #### This first search works and returns the users email address ###
    search_filter = f"(cn={user_name})"
    search_attribute =['mail']
    l.search(search_base='OU=Users,O=Acme',
         search_scope=SUBTREE,
         search_filter=search_filter,
         attributes=search_attribute)

    print('l.response',l.response)
    email = l.response[0]['attributes']['mail'] # All Good to here

    
   
    ### This next search does not work. it just returns and empty list 
    l.search(
        search_base='CN=my-users,OU=MyUsers,OU=Groups,O=Acme',
        search_filter='(cn=my-users)',
        search_scope='SUBTREE',
        attributes = ['member'],
        size_limit=0
    )
    
    print(f'printing entries = {l.entries}') # Outputs []
    print(f'Group response = {l.response}') # This also outputs []
    
    for entry in l.entries: # Never happens
        print(entry.member.values)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to verify that your user is a member of my-users then you dont need the second search.
Instead add the search attribute "memberOf" `search_attribute =['mail', 'memberOf']` to your first search and then parse it the same way you did mail.
Something like this ..

```
    user_group_dn = 'CN=my-users,OU=MyUsers,OU=Groups,O=Acme'
    search_filter = f"(cn={user_name})"
    search_attribute =['mail', 'memberOf']
    l.search(search_base='OU=Users,O=Acme',
         search_scope=SUBTREE,
         search_filter=search_filter,
         attributes=search_attribute)

    print('l.response',l.response)
    email = l.response[0]['attributes']['mail'] 
    memberOf = l.response[0]['attributes']['memberOf'] #This is the key
    #memberOf should bring back ['CN=my-users,OU=MyUsers,OU=Groups,O=Acme','Someothe user groups']

    if user_group_dn in memberOf:
        # do some stuff here. allow login
```